# NullPointerException - JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing

I am getting a `NullPointerException` with `JOptionPane` on Linux with OpenJDK 1.6.0.22.  I alert the user that a certain number of items must be selected.  The thread is running on the Event Dispatch Thread.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "At least one entity must be selected.",
                "Selection Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.X11.XWindowPeer.restoreTransientFor(XWindowPeer.java:1681)
    at sun.awt.X11.XWindowPeer.removeFromTransientFors(XWindowPeer.java:1747)
    at sun.awt.X11.XWindowPeer.setModalBlocked(XWindowPeer.java:1469)
    at sun.awt.X11.XWindowPeer.setModalBlocked(XWindowPeer.java:1440)
    at java.awt.Window.setModalBlocked(Window.java:1359)
    at java.awt.Dialog.unblockWindow(Dialog.java:1597)
    at java.awt.Dialog.modalHide(Dialog.java:1483)
    at java.awt.Dialog.hideAndDisposePreHandler(Dialog.java:1215)
    at java.awt.Dialog.hide(Dialog.java:1255)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1553)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1503)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:881)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1011)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane$3.propertyChange(JOptionPane.java:1021)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:298)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:291)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:229)
    at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Component.java:8148)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.setValue(JOptionPane.java:1964)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicOptionPaneUI$ButtonActionListener.actionPerformed(BasicOptionPaneUI.java:1201)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2012)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2335)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:404)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:253)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6268)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6033)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2045)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4629)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2103)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4455)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4633)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4297)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4227)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2089)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2517)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4455)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:649)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:96)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:608)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:606)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:105)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:622)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:620)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:619)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:275)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:200)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:194)
    at java.awt.Dialog$1.run(Dialog.java:1072)
    at java.awt.Dialog$3.run(Dialog.java:1126)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1124)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(JOptionPane.java:871)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:668)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:639)
    at com.walterjwhite.ui.api.renderer.entity.MultipleEntitySelectorRenderer.isSingleRowSelected(MultipleEntitySelectorRenderer.java:191)
    at com.walterjwhite.ui.api.renderer.entity.MultipleEntitySelectorRenderer.edit(MultipleEntitySelectorRenderer.java:151)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.walterjwhite.ui.api.renderer.callback.ButtonCallbackHandler$1.actionPerformed(ButtonCallbackHandler.java:99)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2012)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2335)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:404)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:253)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6268)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6033)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2045)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4629)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2103)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4455)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4633)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4297)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4227)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2089)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2517)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4455)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:649)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:96)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:608)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:606)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:105)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:622)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:620)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:619)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:275)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:200)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:190)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:185)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:177)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Still seem like a JVM bug. *I would try to upgrade your JDK version version 7 where the bug seems fixed.*

Check these bug reports:

- [**735472** NullPointerException at XWindowPeer.restoreTransientFor() using a JOptionPane](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=735472)
- [**730015** NullPointerException on disposing modal dialog](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=730015)

---

Old (didn't fix your problem):

- [**6431340** NullPointerException on Dialog hide on dual head system (non-xinerama)](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=5be1dc986753fffffffffdb75ed897432322?bug_id=6431340)

Comment: @both: Hum, I'm not that confident.. the stacktraces differ after some depth.. :( Will see if it matches his problem first!

Comment: Hmm, interesting catch, let me see if xinerama works.  I can't get to that website for some reason.

Comment: Nope, enabling xinerama didn't change anything.

Comment: Looks like it was the JDK.  I am now using JDK7.